# Trigger .slideUp at anchor (scroll)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, anchor

I'm trying to trigger an element to slide up when I reach an anchor (**EDIT:** via scroll). The anchor ID is `#blacksection` and the element class is `.vc_tta-panels-container`. I read on another thread that the best way to use an anchor to trigger a JS animation is to trigger an `onclick` event from the anchor using something like:

```
jQuery("#blacksection").trigger('click');
```

And then I'm using;

```
  jQuery("#blacksection").on('click', function() {
    jQuery(".vc_tta-panels-container").slideUp();
```

as the remaining JS. So I have this:

```
<script>
jQuery("#blacksection").trigger('click');
  jQuery("#blacksection").on('click', function() {
    jQuery(".vc_tta-panels-container").slideUp();
});
</script>
```

Which isn't working, only just started learning JS and it's baffling my mind, can anyone shed some light on triggering `slideUp()` for a class when the user scrolls past an anchor (`#blacksection`)?

Answer (score 1):

The `click` event needs to be defined before you call it with the `.trigger()` function.  Also, depending on what sort of default behaviour `#blacksection` has on the click event, you may wish to use `.triggerHandler()` instead, which invokes only the user-defined events:

```
jQuery("#blacksection").on('click', function() {
    jQuery(".vc_tta-panels-container").slideUp();
});
jQuery("#blacksection").triggerHandler('click');
```

---

**EDIT:**

Given your comment, which clarifies things somewhat, the above solution won't work.  You want the `.vc_tta-panels-container` element to slide up when the `#blacksection` element comes into view on screen during/after scrolling.

Thankfully, someone already has this solution here: [Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

To tailor it to your problem, here is a snippet with some HTML and appropriate JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function Utils() {

  }

  Utils.prototype = {
      constructor: Utils,
      isElementInView: function (element, fullyInView) {
          var pageTop = $(window).scrollTop();
          var pageBottom = pageTop + $(window).height();
          var elementTop = $(element).offset().top;
          var elementBottom = elementTop + $(element).height();
          
          if (fullyInView === true) {
              return ((pageTop < elementTop) && (pageBottom > elementBottom));
          } else {
              return ((elementTop <= pageBottom) && (elementBottom >= pageTop));
          }
      }
  }
  

  var Utils = new Utils();
  
   $('#scrollsection').scroll(function() {
    var isElementInView = Utils.isElementInView($('#blacksection'), false);

    if (isElementInView) {
        $('.vc_tta-panels-container').slideUp();
    } else {
        $('.vc_tta-panels-container').slideDown();
    }
  });
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vc_tta-panels-container" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100px; background-color: #f00">
  <span>I will slide up when the word "BAZ" comes into view below</p>
</div>
<div id="scrollsection" style="position:fixed; top: 100px; width: 100%; bottom: 0; overflow-y: scroll">
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    <div id="blacksection">BAZ</div>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
    .<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this, this is the html: `<a id="blacksection"></a><span style="color: #000;">-</span>`. I did have `onclick=".slideUp"` in there as well but it isn't working, do you know how I can link this up correctly?

Comment: The code I gave above should be sufficient.  Since your `<a>` element does not have an `href="{target}"` tag you should be able to use either `.trigger('click')` or `.triggerHandler('click')` to the same effect. If the script is still not working for you, you may need to wrap the entire thing in a `$(document).ready(function() { ..... });` statement, to ensure that your jQuery library loads before the script does.

Comment: Hi thanks again :), this is my JS: `<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
  jQuery("#blacksection").on('click', function() {
    jQuery(".vc_tta-panels-container").slideUp();
});
 jQuery("#blacksection").trigger('click');
});
</script>` and HTML: `<a id="blacksection"></a><span style="color: #000;">-</span>`. Should this be working?

Comment: I've added a snippet to demonstrate functionality. Looking at your original question, it's a little ambiguous... did you want the `slideUp()` only to occur once the `#blacksection` element is clicked?

Comment: Almost, I'm looking to trigger the `slideUp()` for the `.vc_tta-panels-container` when the user scrolls down, past the anchor `#blacksection` rather than on click. I read on another thread that the best way to trigger JS animations from an anchor is to assign an `onclick` action to the anchor. Looking at the code you provided I feel I'm missing JS that defines the scroll action?

Comment: Righto, I misunderstood your original request.  What you want is for a section to slide up once something else comes into view on the screen.  You don't need click events at all, the scroll event is what you need along with a test for visibility.  See my edited answer above.